# Javascript slider works but it's hard-coded

Tags: javascript, slider, dom-events

I need four sliders in one page, all of them with different content.

So far I have created two sliders and they are working fine, but I needed two more sliders.Then I realized that it turned out to be too much code.

Even the dots in sliders are hard-coded!

And I couldn't find a way to make it more dynamic.

**Here is a link to my code:**
[code](https://jsfiddle.net/iki123/Ln0or6bu/4/)

```js
var thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-dots li');
var slider1 = document.querySelector('.slider-1');
var slider2 = document.querySelector('.slider-2');
var slider3 = document.querySelector('.slider-3');
var slider4 = document.querySelector('.slider-4');



var dot1 = document.querySelector('.dot1');
var dot2 = document.querySelector('.dot2');

var dot3 = document.querySelector('.dot3');
var dot4 = document.querySelector('.dot4');

// console.log(thumbnails);

thumbnails.forEach(thumbnail => {

  thumbnail.addEventListener('click', function(item) {
    var dot = item.target;
    console.log(dot);


    if (dot.classList.contains("slider1")) {
      slider2.style.display = 'none';
      slider1.style.display = 'flex';

      dot2.classList.remove('active-dot');
      dot1.classList.add('active-dot');
    } else if (dot.classList.contains("slider2")) {

      slider1.style.display = 'none';
      slider2.style.display = 'flex';

      dot1.classList.remove('active-dot');
      dot2.classList.add('active-dot');
    } else if (dot.classList.contains("slider3")) {
      // dot.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      slider4.style.display = 'none';
      slider3.style.display = 'flex';

      dot4.classList.remove('active-dot');
      dot3.classList.add('active-dot');
    } else if (dot.classList.contains("slider4")) {
      // dot.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      slider3.style.display = 'none';
      slider4.style.display = 'flex';

      dot3.classList.remove('active-dot');
      dot4.classList.add('active-dot');
    }

  })
});
```

```html
<div class="myslider">
  <ul class="slide-dots">
    <li class="slider1 dot1"></li>
    <li class="slider2 dot2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slider slider-1">
    <div class="slider__img">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472718888560-1a1292f1cccb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>kjlaskldjaklsjdklajsdlkjaskldjlkasjdklas</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider slider-2" style="display:none">
    <div class="slider__img">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450820900803-38abb1b52bbe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1347&q=80" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>sssssssss</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- //////SLIDER 2////// -->
<div class="myslider">
  <ul class="slide-dots">
    <li class="slider3 dot3"></li>
    <li class="slider4 dot4"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="slider slider-3">
    <div class="slider__img">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472718888560-1a1292f1cccb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum doret sit amet</h1>
        <p>asdasdasd</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider slider-4" style="display:none">
    <div class="slider__img">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450820900803-38abb1b52bbe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1347&q=80" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="contents">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum amet sit doret</h1>
        <p>ssssssssaaaaaaas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This question is asking about the art of ["refactoring"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring). When you find yourself repeating code over and over again, you want to refactor that code to its own function so that you can run it easily over and over. The trick here is that you've presented us with a lot of code and told us to do the refactoring. How about reading up on the subject, try some things, then come back with specific questions.

Comment: I know it doesn't solve your problem but there are a variety of carousel/slideshow tutorials out there: [w3 schools has one with just vanilla js and css](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp). You can also use a predefined framework like [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), or just implement [bootstraps carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for your suggestion.